# transition ease-out, right to left, how?

Tags: css, css-transitions

ease-out normally move from left to right, now I want change it to right to left
How can I set it in my CSS ?

example :

```
transition:         background-position 150ms ease-out;
-moz-transition:    background-position 150ms ease-out;
-webkit-transition: background-position 150ms ease-out;
-o-transition:      background-position 150ms ease-out;
```

Comment: use jQuery it is and will be easear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no default *direction* for [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)ing the properties. And `ease-out` is just a *[transition timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function)*:

From the [Spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#transition-timing-function_tag):

> The `transition-timing-function` property describes how the
>   intermediate values used during a transition will be calculated. It
>   allows for a transition to change speed over its duration. These
>   effects are commonly called easing functions. In either case, a
>   mathematical function that provides a smooth curve is used.

**The direction of `background-position` transition, depends on the *first* and the *last* values.**

For instance:

```css
.box {
    /* other styles here... */
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300);
    transition: background-position 150ms ease-out;
}

/* Move the background image from right to left */
.box.rtl { background-position: 0 center; }
.box.rtl:hover { background-position: 100% center; }

/* Move the background image from left to right */
.box.ltr { background-position: 100% center; }
.box.ltr:hover { background-position: 0 center; }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/jxTN8/)**.

Comment: what if we use text, like fontawesome and not background?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    float: right;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: width 2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}

body {
    width: 500px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>sample</div>

</body>
</html>
```

By floating the div to the right, you will have your div starting at the right side. And when it expands, it will expand to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple sliding left-right CSS using transition.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    
        <style>
        .parent{
        display:flex;
        overflow:hidden;
        }
        .red,.blue,.green,.orange{
        min-width:300px;
        height:300px;
        margin:10px;
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        }
        .d-none{
         display:none;
        }
        .red{
         background-color:red;
        }
    
        .blue{
    
        background-color:blue;
        }
    
        .green{
        background-color:green;
        }
    
        .orange{
        background-color:orange;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
    
        
        <div id="parent"class="parent">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="orange"></div>

        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="orange"></div>

        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="orange"></div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="next()">next</button>
        <button onclick="prev()">prev</button>
        <script>
         let left="0";
         let parent = document.getElementById("parent")
         let children = Array.from(parent.children)
         
         function next(){
           left = left - 320
           children.forEach(child=>{
           child.style.left = left+"px"
           child.style.transition = "all 500ms ease-in-out"
           })
         }
         
          function prev(){
          left = left + 320
         children.forEach(child=>{
           child.style.left = left+"px"
           child.style.transition = "all 500ms ease-in-out"
    
           })
              
         }
         
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple, 
Like your left to right Transition and if you want right to left Transition just use `float:right;` when you are styling you *Div(ect)*.